# Routing within a single page app integration

Tags: routes, routing

I'm using Craft as the backend for an app and VueJS along with Element API to deliver the content.

Everything so far is working sweet, except when I try to pull up the detail page for an entry because in Craft, the route doesn't exist.

To be clear, my main listing page and links work but if I try to visit `http://localhost/slug/id` directly, I get a 404.

I know within the context of something like Laravel, I could do

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

Is there something similar I could do with Craft?

I should add I have user registration and aspects that vue can't handle because Craft doesn't have a full crud api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To pull this off, first you’ll have to make sure all of your Element API endpoints begin with something consistent, like `api/` or `data/`, etc.

Then create a route in `craft/config/routes.php` that will match everything besides those Element API endpoints:

```php
<?php

return array(
    '(?!api\/).*' => 'index'
);
```

`'index`' is the template path the requests should be routed to, so tweak that if needed.

If you have any other routes defined in there, make sure they go before this one.

> I should add I have user registration and aspects that vue can't handle because Craft doesn't have a full crud api.

You can use the same controller actions the Control Panel uses. There are a few examples, including [user registration](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) at the bottom of the templating docs.

If you want to keep these handled by custom pages, you’ll need to add routes for them in `routes.php`, or else they will stop working due to that new catchall route. Craft only attempts its default behavior of matching the URI to a public template as a last resort; if a route matches the URI, that route will take precedence.

Comment: ah, looks like that'll burst the Element API endpoints though, do I have any other options?

Comment: looks like the way around this is to do `post/(?P<slug>[^\/]+)\/(?P<number>\d+)` - ideally I'd like to drop `post` but this will do for now

Comment: @StevenGrant Ah, right. Just updated the route example to ignore Element API endpoints (assuming you can give all your endpoints a consistent prefix, e.g. `api/`).

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun a little here. Despite having the route example you've given, I'm still managing to 404 when I try visit any URL other than the home page or the API endpoints.

Comment: Do you have an `index` template? (`index.html` or `index.twig`)

Comment: That has been my experience with route 404s too. After banging my head for a while, I find an error with the template I entered.

Comment: yeah, `index.twig` which works fine for the home page. Can't see any errors with the template either and given it works on home, should work for others.

Comment: just tried a fresh install with the same route and see the same thing. Thought it could possibly be Laravel Valet but MAMP is the same.

Comment: @StevenGrant Sorry, rookie mistake. Just fixed the route example.

Comment: @BrandonKelly BOOM! I also had to tell Craft not to allow that section to have its own URLs. This will make for a solid blog post on gotchas :)

Comment: @StevenGrant Looking forward to it!

Answer (score 6):

In case someone uses Craft 3, this should work:

`<?
return array(
    '<url:(?!api\/).*>' => ['template' => 'index']
);`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why Davids solution doesn't work for me, I'm using the following (Craft 3.2.8):

```
return [
    '<url:(?!api\b)\b\w+>' => ['template' => 'index'],
];
```